# "you get A instead of B, as with C", then who goes with C?

Tags: ambiguity

In Shane Cook's book [CUDA Programming 2012](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124159338), page 87, there is such a sentence:

> As a consequence you get two transactions instead of one, as with the **stripe layout**.

The author talks about two kind of layouts: "square layout" and "stripe layout". From the quoted sentence, the author is very clear, square layout costs two transactions.

And what baffles me is: According to English syntax, what is the book author's opinion on stripe layout,

- we get two transactions, or
- we get one transaction?

[image]

Comment: The actual text as cited doesn't explicitly state that the stripe layout only has one transaction, and the *syntactic construction* is inherently ambiguous as regards whether ***as with the stripe layout*** refers back to preceding ***two transactions*** or ***one***. So there's not really a question about use of English here, but *pragmatically*, I'd say it's virtually certain the stripe layout only has ***one*** transaction. Whatever that means. Apart from anything else, if the stripe layout *also* had two transactions, why raise the possibility of only one anyway? When would *that* happen?

Comment: But I'm afraid stripe layout does have two transactions, same as square layout, because the author says "you get marginally quicker memory access". I think "marginally" means "very slightly" here. If memory access transactions is "once" vs "twice”, then the former should be twice as quicker.

Comment: It sounds like you know the subject matter much better than me. Like I said, there's no easy way to choose between the two possible meanings just by looking at the syntax, because it's *inherently* ambiguous. Hence it's a pointless question here if that's what you're asking about; we can only discuss the nature of the syntactically ambiguous construction itself. But I must admit I thought "marginally quicker memory access" might reasonably reflect the fact that two transactions at a time can access more memory than one transaction, leading to faster *total throughput.*

Comment: Thank you, I got your idea. Before I ask it here, I did not realize it is ambiguous. If it is ambiguous, then "you get A instead of B, as with C" should be considered awful tech wording. BTW: By author's context, "do once" is definitely quicker than "do twice", because the goal is the same, read 128-bytes of data from GPU RAM into GPU core.

Comment: If I knew absolutely nothing about the subject matter (and wasn't trying to work it out using pragmatics / semantics), my *default* assumption for your text would be that ***as with the stripe layout*** refers back to preceding ***two transactions*** rather than ***one***, because of the comma. I'd expect the comma (or a dash) to come after ***two transactions*** if we were supposed to associate ***stripe layout*** with ***one** [transaction]*. But you're right - it's badly phrased / punctuated.

Comment: It would probably help to look at the referenced figure! But there must be somewhere on Stack Exchange where you can ask software engineers about caching strategies, rather than asking linguists.

Comment: Disambiguation is necessary where there is any hint of the possibility of  misinterpretation [Grice]. **SO:** As a consequence you get, as with the stripe layout. two transactions instead of one. // As a consequence you get two transactions instead of the single one you get with the stripe layout.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase . . .

> One of the reasons you would choose a square layout is that you get
> slightly quicker memory access with a single 128-byte transaction. The
> square layout is a single transaction. (*Except* if the array is small,
> in which case you’ll get two transactions, just like the stripe
> layout.)

So stripe layouts and small-array square layouts take two transactions. This would make that clearer:

> *As a consequence you get two transactions, as with the stripe layout,
> instead of one.*